# How to read xml child of childnode

Tags: xml, delphi

I need help about xml file:

```
<xmlData date="11.04.2014 18:59:15">
 <Table>
   <ean>888182228609</ean>
   <ident>YH5G16EA</ident>
   <properties>
     <property title="Pomnilnik">4GB</property>
     <property title="Trdi disk">500GB</property>
     <property title="Optična enota">BREZ</property>
   </properties>
 </Table>
 <Table>
   <ean>888182228609</ean>
   <ident>YH5G16EA</ident>
   <properties>
     <property title="Pomnilnik">5GB</property>
     <property title="Trdi disk">600GB</property>
     <property title="Optična enota">BREZ</property>
   </properties>
 </Table>
 <Table>
   <ean>888182228609</ean>
   <ident>YH5G16EA</ident>
   <properties>
     <property title="Pomnilnik">7GB</property>
     <property title="Trdi disk">700GB</property>
     <property title="Optična enota">BREZ</property>
   </properties>
 </Table>
</xmlData>
```

I know how to read `<ean>` and `<ident>` but I have a problem reading `<property>`, I would like to get result like "pomnilnik:7GB" or "Trdi disk:700GB".

If I use this code:

```delphi
procedure TForm1.BitBtn4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DOC:IXMLDocument;
  i: Integer;
  OrderChilds, properties_Node: IXMLNode;
begin
  DOC := LoadXMLDocument('c:\temp\diss.xml');
  for i := 0 to DOC.ChildNodes.Nodes['xmlData'].ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
  begin
    OrderChilds := DOC.ChildNodes.Nodes['xmlData'].ChildNodes[i];
    if OrderChilds.NodeName = 'Table' then  
    begin
      properties_Node := OrderChilds.ChildNodes.Nodes['properties'];
      if Assigned(properties_Node) then 
        Memo1.Lines.Add(properties_Node.ChildNodes.Nodes['property'].NodeValue)
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I only get the first property in each table. I would like to read all properties in first table, and then go to next table and read properties and so on.

Comment: You're pretty close. You already know how to iterate child nodes of a node (you're doing that for `<table>` nodes), so just apply the same also for `<property>` nodes. Btw. this task better fits for a SAX parser.

Answer (score 3):

You have to loop over all childnodes in the properties_Node. The same as you did it with the xmlData.

```
propChildList := properties_Node.ChildNodes;
for j := 0 to propChildList.Count - 1 do begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(propChildList.Nodes[j].NodeValue);
end;
```

Here the full working example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DOC:IXMLDocument;
  i, j: Integer;
  OrderChilds, properties_Node: IXMLNode;
  propChildList: IXMLNodeList;
begin
  DOC := LoadXMLDocument('c:\temp\diss.xml');
  for i := 0 to DOC.ChildNodes.Nodes['xmlData'].ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
  begin
    OrderChilds := DOC.ChildNodes.Nodes['xmlData'].ChildNodes[i];
    if OrderChilds.NodeName = 'Table' then
    begin
      properties_Node := OrderChilds.ChildNodes.Nodes['properties'];
      if Assigned(properties_Node) then begin
        propChildList := properties_Node.ChildNodes;
        for j := 0 to propChildList.Count - 1 do begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add(propChildList.Nodes[j].NodeValue);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @user2997342: If the answer was useful to you please vote it up, if it helped you solve your problem consider marking it as the accepted answer. These are the proper ways to say "thank you" around here.